# How did I get two badges for an old answer with no rep changes?

Tags: support, badges

I got two badges this morning.  However, I don't understand how that could have happened.

[image: Achievements menu with two badges highlighted]

[The answer in question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14275224/exit-after-trap-fires/14275357#14275357) shows [no recent reputation changes on its timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14275357/timeline).

So why and how exactly did I receive [these](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/19/enlightened?userid=874188) two [badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/23/nice-answer?userid=874188)?

Comment: Sorry about "the answer in question" ... Couldn't resist.

Comment: Is it possible that the +2 you received yesterday for a user removed was for a user who downvoted that answer and it has been sitting at a score of 9 all this time and with the removal of his downvote it just went up to 10, thereby earning both those badges?

Comment: @n8te I entertained some speculations along those lines, too, but it seemed far-fetched at first.  But that's an astute observation and now that I think about it, maybe that's actually quite plausible.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

n8te called it: until 20 hours ago, that answer scored 9. With the downvote removed, it still scored 9... Until the score was recalculated automatically just over three hours ago, at which point it scored 10 and became eligible for those badges.